# Find minimum and maximum values in a hash

Tags: perl, hashmap

I have a hash which stores strings as keys and their occurrence as values.

```
$VAR1 = {
          'ABCD' => 2,
          'EFGH' => 7,
          'IJKL' => 17,
          'MNOP' => 2,
           'OPMN' => 300,
           'QRST' => 300,
           'DEAC' => 300
}
```

I want to find minimum and maximum of the values for this hash. Eg min = 2 and max = 300

I tried following code which gave error `Can't use string ("17") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at`

```
$minAssigned = min(@{$countPat{$pat4C}});

$maxAssigned = max(@{$countPat{$pat4C}});
```

How can I resolve this error. Also once I have these numbers I want to loop through the values of the same hash minAssigned to maxAssigned times and print the total occurrence of the values. For example the value 2 occurs 2 times, Value 17 occurs 1 time, value 300 occurs 3 times.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [values](https://perldoc.pl/values) to get the list of hash values.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use List::Util qw{ min max };

my $h = {
          'ABCD' => 2,
          'EFGH' => 7,
          'IJKL' => 17,
          'MNOP' => 2,
          'OPMN' => 300,
          'QRST' => 300,
          'DEAC' => 300

};

print min(values %$h), "\n";
print max(values %$h), "\n";
```

Use another hash to count the frequencies:

```perl
my %freq;
++$freq{$_} for values %$h;
for my $k (keys %freq) {
    print "$k occurs $freq{$k} times.\n";
}
```

In a time critical loop and for high number of values, you can switch to `minmax` from [List::MoreUtils](http://p3rl.org/List::MoreUtils) (or [List::SomeUtils](http://p3rl.org/List::SomeUtils) or [List::AllUtils](http://p3rl.org/List::AllUtils)).

```perl
my ($min, $max) = minmax(values %$h);
```